# 'ASP.testproject_vending_detail_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'loadArea_Click"? when project is uploaded to online server plesk

Tags: c#, asp.net, plesk

Anybody know how to resolve the issue:

> "CS1061: 'ASP.testproject_vending_detail_aspx' does not contain a
>   definition for 'loadArea_Click"?

This is Button Onclick event. Same is happening with the radioButtonList onSelectedIndexChanged event.

I have the function definition in the code behind and it is working perfectly on localhost. But when I upload the code to the server and then try to run. It gives me the above error. 
I have checked the files several times and everything seems fine.
I am searching it on google and applied all the found solutions but nothing worked for me.

This is my detail.aspx.cs code:

```
 SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string area;

    DAL.Class1 dalclass = new DAL.Class1();
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList itemInfo = new ArrayList();
    int id = 0;
    String productdesc = "";

    public string sendArea()
    {
        return area;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try { 

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["Order"] == null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("url");
                    dt.Columns.Add("name");
                    dt.Columns.Add("price");
                    dt.Columns.Add("quantity");
                    dt.Columns.Add("tot_price");
                    dt.Columns.Add("id");
                    dt.Columns.Add("displayinfo");
                    dt.Columns.Add("machineserialno");
                    dt.Columns.Add("itemcode");



                    Session["Order"] = dt;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Order"];


                }
            }

            try
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["itemid"] != null)
                { 
                    if(Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1013" || 
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1014" ||
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1017" ||
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1018" ||
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1019" ||
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1020" ||
                        Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1021")
                    {
                        potDiv.Visible = true;
                    }

                    else if (Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1025")
                    {
                        legpack.Visible = true;
                    }

                    else if (Request.QueryString["itemid"] == "1026")
                    {
                        wingspak.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }



        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Save the selected value as a session variable
        Session["Value"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

    protected void  loadArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        string longitude2;
        string latitude;
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            string r = Txt_postCode.Text;
            string VALUE = r.Replace(" ","");


             string url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/"+ VALUE + "?key=AjIx2FPv6ieU1ZH9K8KCzYU5trwHUO__aP7VaHaKEf7TJAQtcP96HZ2qGS2OxJEW";
        //    string url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/MK146JY?key=AjIx2FPv6ieU1ZH9K8KCzYU5trwHUO__aP7VaHaKEf7TJAQtcP96HZ2qGS2OxJEW";
            // attempt to download JSON data as a string
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                List<string> data = json_data.Split('[').ToList<string>();

                string val = data[4];

                List<string> latlng = val.Split(',').ToList<string>();

                latitude = latlng[0];
                string longitude = latlng[1];

                List<string> longitude1 = longitude.Split(']').ToList<string>();
                longitude2 = longitude1[0];

                string val1 = data[4];






            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                string msg;
                msg = ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
        }



        RadioButtonList1.Visible = true;

        string text = Txt_postCode.Text;


        string code = text;

        string m_ConnectionString = "Data Source=43.255.152.26;Initial Catalog=Yumchop;User ID=Yumchop;Password='Yumchop@123';trusted_connection=false";
        conn = new SqlConnection(m_ConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YumChop_Distance WHERE Postal_Code=@postCode", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", code);

        string lat = null;
        string lng = null;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                Txt_postCode.Text = "No data";
            }
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lat = reader["lat"].ToString();
                lng = reader["lng"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = "Select your area ";
            newItem.Value = "0";
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 3 ID,Area_Name,Full_Address, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@latitude) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@longitude) ) + sin( radians(@latitude) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM YumChop_Distance Order By ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@latitude) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(@longitude) ) + sin( radians(@latitude) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@latitude", latitude);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longitude", longitude2);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            int i = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                i++;
                if(i==1)
                {
                    string s = reader["distance"].ToString();
                    string sr = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(".")+2);
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Text = reader["Area_Name"].ToString() + " - "+sr +" KM away";
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Value = reader["Full_Address"].ToString() + " - " + sr + " KM away";

                }
                else if (i==2)
                {
                    string s = reader["distance"].ToString();
                    string sr = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(".") + 2);
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Text = reader["Area_Name"].ToString() + " - " + sr + " KM away";
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Value = reader["Full_Address"].ToString() + " - " + sr + " KM away";

                }
                else if(i==3)
                {
                    string s = reader["distance"].ToString();
                    string sr = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(".") + 2);
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[2].Text = reader["Area_Name"].ToString() + " - " + sr+ " KM away";
                    this.RadioButtonList1.Items[2].Value = reader["Full_Address"].ToString() + " - " + sr + " KM away";

                }
                ListItem newItem1 = new ListItem();
                newItem1.Text = reader["Area_Name"].ToString();
                newItem1.Value = reader["ID"].ToString();
            }

            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

This is detail.aspx code:

```
  <div>
                                      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                                   </div>

                                   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                         <div >
                                            <h3>Enter Postal Code </h3>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_postCode" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter Postal code to get nearby Veding Machine"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:Button ID="Btn_postCode" runat="server"  OnClick="loadArea_Click" Text="Check"></asp:Button>


                                             <h3>Near By Machines</h3>
                                         <br />
                                             <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"  onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="False">
                                                <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem  ></asp:ListItem>
                                                 <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>



                                        </div>

                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" >

                                       <ProgressTemplate>
                                          Loading...
                                       </ProgressTemplate>

                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: can you include the top line in your `aspx` page. It should start with `<%@ Page`...

Comment: Page name is wrong.

Comment: @Erresen <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="VendingMachine.detail" %>
 this is the top line in aspx.

Comment: I have checked entirely. The page name is correct and there is one more button in the code which I have not mentioned here. It works perfect.@IrishChieftain